# XStream and using 'ToAttributedValueConverter' for two similar but different XML fields

Tags: java, xstream

In my XML files I have lines like this;

```
    <text id="name">Bu ilk rule</text>
    <text id="bundleName">Rule.behavior</text>
```

So my Text class is like this:

```
@XStreamConverter(value = ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings = {"value"})
@XStreamAlias("text")
public class Text {

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    String id = "unset";
    String value = "0";
}
```

And it works. But today I got this in an XML:

```
        <text id="targetAttribute">game.devices.touches.touch1.y</text>
        <text id="RHS">
          <expression>
            <string>acos(x)</string>
          </expression>
        </text>
```

And it does not work. If I remove the `@XStreamConverter` I get an output like this:

```
        <text id="targetAttribute"/>
        <text id="RHS">
          <expression>
            <string>acos(x)</string>
          </expression>
        </text>
```

What is the workaround for this?

**Edit:**

After Matthias's answer the closest I can get to desired format is this:

```
        <text id="RHS">
          <expression>
            <string>acos(x)</string>
          </expression>
        </text>
```

But this method fails, it starts not showing the "value" field:

```
        <text id="name"/>
        <text id="bundleName"/>
        <text id="targetAttribute"/>
```

With this class:

```
@XStreamAlias("text")

class Test {

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    String id = "unset";
    String value = "0";
    myString string = new myString();
    Expression expression = new Expression();

}
```

Also, I do the reading like this, so it must work when doing this:

```
String xml1 = readFile("C:\\1.xml");
Actor actorNew = (Actor) xstream.fromXML(xml1);

String xmlNew = xstream.toXML(actorNew);
System.out.println(xmlNew);
```

**Edit2:**

myString classs for `<string>` in XML:

```
@XStreamConverter(value = ToAttributedValueConverter.class, strings = {"value"})
public class myString {

    @XStreamAlias("string")
    String value = "";

}
```

And here is a zoomed-out view of the XML I'm trying to read:

```
<behaviors>
        <behavior id="id384781" class="ChangeAttributeAction" enabled="true">
          <attributes>
            <text id="name">Change Attribute</text>
            <text id="bundleName">ChangeAttribute.behavior</text>
            <text id="targetAttribute">game.devices.touches.touch1.y</text>
            <text id="RHS">
              <expression>
                <string>acos(x)</string>
              </expression>
            </text>
          </attributes>
        </behavior>
</behaviors>
```

All is working until the text with id = "RHS"

**Edit3:**

I tried something like that on custom converter but didn't work:

```
@Override
public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.expression = new Expression();
    test.expression.string = new myString();
    test.value = reader.getValue();
    test.id = reader.getAttribute("id");
    reader.moveDown();
    reader.moveDown();
    test.expression.string.value = reader.getValue();
    return test;
}
```

**Edit4**

**WOOOOHOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO I GOT IT AT LAST!**

Here is how I did it:

```
class ValueConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return Test.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        Test src = (Test) source;
        writer.addAttribute("id", src.id);
        writer.setValue(src.value);

        if (src.expression.string.value.length() > 0) {
            writer.startNode("expression");
            writer.startNode("string");
            writer.setValue(src.expression.string.value);
            writer.endNode();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.id = reader.getAttribute("id");
        test.value = reader.getValue();
        if (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
            reader.moveDown();
            reader.moveDown();
            test.expression.string.value = reader.getValue();

        }
        return test;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by changing the converter MAtthias mentioned;

```
class ValueConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return Test.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        Test src = (Test) source;
        writer.addAttribute("id", src.id);
        writer.setValue(src.value);

        if (src.expression.string.value.length() > 0) {
            writer.startNode("expression");
            writer.startNode("string");
            writer.setValue(src.expression.string.value);
            writer.endNode();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.id = reader.getAttribute("id");
        test.value = reader.getValue();
        if (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
            reader.moveDown();
            reader.moveDown();
            test.expression.string.value = reader.getValue();

        }
        return test;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the code you show, cannot produce this XML. I guess somewhere in your real code, there is some inheritance (A class Expression extending your Test class) which is producing this result. Seems as if the `ToAttributedValueConverter` does not really work for derived classes and gets ignored there.

If you have a more complex object structure which you want to map to a very specific XML representation, you should use converters. In doubt you can always create a custom converter which handles the marshalling / unmarshalling.
For those converters, you can easily define for which classes they should be used (see the `canConvert(Class)` method.

I did this for you for a very similar piece of code:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;

@XStreamAlias("text")
class Test {

  String id = "unset";
  String value = "0";
}

@XStreamAlias("expression")
class Expression extends Test {
  Expression() {
    value = "acos(x)";
  }
}

class ValueConverter implements Converter {

  @Override
  public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
    return Test.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
  }

  @Override
  public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
    Test src = (Test)source;
    writer.addAttribute("id", src.id);
    writer.setValue(src.value);
  }

  @Override
  public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.value = reader.getValue();
    test.id = reader.getAttribute("id");
    return test;
  }

}

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    xStream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
    System.out.println("BEFORE setting a converter:");
    System.out.println(xStream.toXML(new Test()));
    System.out.println(xStream.toXML(new Expression()));
    xStream.registerConverter(new ValueConverter());
    System.out.println("\nAFTER setting a converter:");
    System.out.println(xStream.toXML(new Test()));
    System.out.println(xStream.toXML(new Expression()));
  }
}
```

Running this, you get the following output:

```
<text>
  <id>unset</id>
  <value>0</value>
</text>
<expression>
  <id>unset</id>
  <value>acos(x)</value>
</expression>

AFTER setting a converter:
<text id="unset">0</text>
<expression id="unset">acos(x)</expression>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I've been playing around with it for a while but I still couldn't get it to work. I updated the question. And in your answer the format is different, `<expression>` should start before `<text>` ends. I guess I should tinker around with ValueConverter, but I couldn't menage to.

Comment: Could you also post the code of the Expression class? I'll see if I can get it to work then.

Comment: I had nothing on Expression class, than I added `myString string = new myString();` to see if it would make any difference. And I'll update the question with myString class now.

Comment: I couldn't get 1 step further, any news from you? :)

Comment: XStream just won't see the `<expression>` class and its subclass `<string>`. I've written different converters but even I get the desired format, I can't get the value, which is _acos(x)_ in our case. I shouldn't have to put that in manually, it should read it from XML but it can't.